# Почему не перерисовывается окно функцией repaint()?

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ComponentGraph extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton bt=new JButton("OK!");  
    FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
    ListenEngine le=new ListenEngine();

    static int x=100;
    static int y=600;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawLine(x,x,y,y); 
    }

    public void ComponentGraph() {

        bt.addActionListener(new ComponentGraph());

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.add(bt);
        c.setLayout(fl);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setSize(800,800); 
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void write()
    {
        x=x+50;
        y=y+50;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComponentGraph cg=new ComponentGraph();
        cg.ComponentGraph();      
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ComponentGraph.write();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Вам стоит добавить больше информации о вашей проблеме. Но навскидку нужно смотреть в сторону validate().

Answer (score 2):

Потому что:

```
bt.addActionListener(new ComponentGraph());
```

Вы создаете *новый* объект и назначаете его в качестве слушателя. Соответственно, `repaint()` вызывается у этого нового объекта, он не виден, поэтому на экране ничего не происходит. Напишите:

```
bt.addActionListener( this );
```

чтобы нажатия мыши обрабатывал ваш видимый фрейм.

Comment: Да! заработало!! блин как долго я искал примитивный пример работы  перерисовки)))

Comment: а если обработчик будет в другом, внешнем классе, как ему передать что именно нужно repaint() ? пробовал таким методом ComponentGraph.repaint(); но пишет ошибка

Comment: @user198532 вам нужно как-то передать в обработчик ваш фрейм, например через параметр конструктора обработчика, в конструкторе обработчика сохранить этот параметр в поле, и потом вызывать `имя_поля.repaint()`